# Failed to install DotNetNuke extension in Visual studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, dotnetnuke

Failed to install this extension [DotNetNuke](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Chris-Hammond.DotNetNukeDNNDevelopmentProjectTemplates) .vsix file into VS 2015 enterprise, the Error log file details are:
[ErrorLog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWX3n.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That template only works on VS 2017.  You need [version 8 of the template for 2015](https://github.com/ChrisHammond/DNNTemplates/releases/tag/v08.00.00).

Comment: When I Installed this template and created a MVC module, when I tried to build the MVC module it gives multiple errors because it missing many reference such as DotNetNuke.dll, any Idea why this errors?

Comment: When created the MVC module project, did you select the DesktopModules/MVC folder?  Also, are you building the module in a DNN8 or higher environment?

Comment: My DNN version is 9.1.1 (the last version), and I creates the MVC module project by clicking New Project -- > Select DotNetNuke Template --> and select --> DNN (DotNetNuke) 8/9 C# DAL MVC Module, The project Target framework is 4.5.1 and changing it to 4.5 didn't help (as some web search results suggested)